# How to make for loop produce five unique values

Tags: php

I created this code so that it will give me five value based on probability. Then insert into an array. It works but I want it to give me 5 unique value. If I used `array_unique()` it will make the output unique so the end result will be 3 or 2 or sometimes 4 value because it removes duplicates. but I want them to be 5 unique values all the time. How can I do This.

This is my code

```
<?php

$random= [];
function getRandomWeightedElement(array $weightedValues)
{
    $array = array();

    foreach ($weightedValues as $key => $weight) {
        $array = array_merge(array_fill(0, $weight, $key), $array);
    }

    return $array[array_rand($array)];
}

global $res;
            
for($i=0; $i<5 ; $i++)
{
    $res=getRandomWeightedElement(array('A'=>0.05, 'B'=>0.05,'C'=>0.10,'D'=>5,'E'=>5,'F'=>5,'G'=>5,'H'=>13,'I'=>16,'J'=>16,'K'=>16.8,'L'=>18));

    global $stopAt; 

    if ($res=='A') {
        $stopAt = 20;
    } else if ($res=='B') {
        $stopAt = 50;
    } else if ($res=='C') {
        $stopAt = 70;
    } else if ($res=='D') {
        $stopAt = 100;
    } else if ($res=='E') {
        $stopAt = 135;
    } else if ($res=='F') {
        $stopAt = 165;
        continue;
    } else if ($res=='G') {
        $stopAt = 190;
    } else if ($res=='H') {
        $stopAt = 230;
    } else if ($res=='I') {
        $stopAt = 265;
    } else if ($res=='J') {
        $stopAt = 292;
    } else if ($res=='K') {
        $stopAt = 320;
    } else if ($res=='L') {
        $stopAt = 350;
    } else{
        echo "error";
    }
        
    $random[]= $stopAt;
}

print_r(array_unique($random));
?>
```

Comment: Each time you make a call to `getRandomWeightedElement()`, remove the randomly chosen item from that array that you pass into the function, so that there isn't a chance of choosing it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to check if the value already exists in the result array, you can use `in_array()` for that. But that means you have to keep looping until you have 5 unique results which means changing the loop.

```
$random= [];
function getRandomWeightedElement(array $weightedValues)
{
    $array = array();

    foreach ($weightedValues as $key => $weight) {
        $array = array_merge(array_fill(0, $weight, $key), $array);
    }

    return $array[array_rand($array)];
}

//for($i=0; $i<5 ; $i++) {

$params = array('A'=>0.05, 'B'=>0.05,'C'=>0.10,'D'=>5, 
                'E'=>5,'F'=>5,'G'=>5,'H'=>13,'I'=>16,
                'J'=>16,'K'=>16.8,'L'=>18);
$notGot5 = true;
while ( $notGot5 ) {

    $res=getRandomWeightedElement($params);

    if ($res=='A') {
        $stopAt = 20;
    } else if ($res=='B') {
        $stopAt = 50;
    } else if ($res=='C') {
        $stopAt = 70;
    } else if ($res=='D') {
        $stopAt = 100;
    } else if ($res=='E') {
        $stopAt = 135;
    } else if ($res=='F') {
        $stopAt = 165;
        continue;
    } else if ($res=='G') {
        $stopAt = 190;
    } else if ($res=='H') {
        $stopAt = 230;
    } else if ($res=='I') {
        $stopAt = 265;
    } else if ($res=='J') {
        $stopAt = 292;
    } else if ($res=='K') {
        $stopAt = 320;
    } else if ($res=='L') {
        $stopAt = 350;
    } else{
        echo "error";
    }
   
    if ( in_array($stopAt, $random) ) {
        // keep looking
        continue;
    } else  {     
        $random[]= $stopAt;
    }
    // loop terminates when we have 5 in the array
    $notGot5 = count($randon) != 5;
}

print_r($random);
```

Comment: it gives an error `PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'continue' (T_CONTINUE) in /home/ImfXny/prog.php on line 55`

Comment: Sorry TYPO in `if ( in_array($stopAt, $random) ) {` I missed a `)` Fixed it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing several `if` statements to choose random values, you can choose the values directly from the array itself.

The below code should give you what you want:

```
$valuesToChooseFrom = [
    'A' => 0.1,
    'B' => 0.3,
    'C' => 3.1,
    'D' => 20,
    'E' => 10,
    'F' => 4,
    'G' => 222
];
$result = [];
              
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $key = array_rand($valuesToChooseFrom);
    $result[$key] = $valuesToChooseFrom[$key];
    
    unset($valuesToChooseFrom[$key]);
}

print_r($result);
```

And gives:

```
Array
(
    [F] => 4
    [G] => 222
    [D] => 20
    [B] => 0.3
    [E] => 10
)
```

It works by selecting a random element from the `valuesToChooseFrom` array, using the [array_rand()](https://php.net/array_rand) function. The `array_rand` function selects a random element from the array you pass it, and returns that element (the key in this case, since we are working with a 2 dimensional array). You then  add an item to the `result` array, with the key being the key returned from the `array_rand` call, and the value being the value in the `valuesToChooseFrom` array, using the key to index the `valuesToChooseFrom` array.

To prevent PHP from choosing the same value more than once, you have to remove the value `valuesToChooseFrom` array. This is what the `unset($valuesToChooseFrom[$key]);` line does.

`array_rand()` also accepts a second argument, which is the number of random elements to select from the array. If you pass in `5` as the second argument, it will choose 5 random elements from the array. And since they all appear to be unique (I could be mistaken), a better way would be to do `array_random($valuesToChooseFrom, 5)` to select 5 random values from the array.

But since that method only returns the keys, you will need to do a `foreach` loop to loop over the returned array, and then use each key to grab the value from the `valuesToChooseFrom` array.